# VBA to reorganize 100+ columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I pull data from Tableau multiple times (50-150x) throughout the day.  We're talking about 100+ columns, and anywhere from 5 to 5000 rows.  One issue is that Tableau sorts the columns by headers in alphabetical order, but I need it in a specific order.  So, I recorded a macro of manually cutting/inserting each row- which took FOREVER.  Then I removed the 'scrolling' bits of code, along with disabling screen updates to speed it up a bit, but it's still quite slow.  Sometimes taking more than 45 seconds to run.  Considering the rate I perform this task in a day, this is substantially slower than I know is possible.  Ultimately, I need to map the columns in this order:

```
Tableau Column  |   Becomes
----    ----    ----
L   |   A
AH  |   B
CD  |   C
AG  |   D
AO  |   E
J   |   F
AX  |   G
AZ  |   H
AQ  |   I
AR  |   J
BB  |   K
BC  |   L
AT  |   M
AS  |   N
AU  |   O
AV  |   P
AW  |   Q
BA  |   R
AY  |   S
BJ  |   T
BY  |   U
BF  |   V
CA  |   W
CB  |   X
BG  |   Y
BZ  |   Z
CC  |   AA
B   |   AB
C   |   AC
D   |   AD
E   |   AE
CU  |   AF
BH  |   AG
BI  |   AH
CW  |   AI
BX  |   AJ
BW  |   AK
BV  |   AL
DC  |   AM
DA  |   AN
DB  |   AO
K   |   AP
BK  |   AQ
BL  |   AR
BM  |   AS
BN  |   AT
BO  |   AU
BP  |   AV
BQ  |   AW
BR  |   AX
BS  |   AY
BT  |   AZ
BU  |   BA
CZ  |   BB
AP  |   BC
BD  |   BD
AF  |   BE
CE  |   BF
CF  |   BG
CG  |   BH
CT  |   BI
A   |   BJ
BE  |   BK
N   |   BL
O   |   BM
CH  |   BN
CI  |   BO
CJ  |   BP
CK  |   BQ
CL  |   BR
CM  |   BS
CN  |   BT
CO  |   BU
CP  |   BV
CQ  |   BW
CR  |   BX
CS  |   BY
F   |   BZ
G   |   CA
H   |   CB
I   |   CC
R   |   CD
P   |   CE
AI  |   CF
AM  |   CG
AB  |   CH
AK  |   CI
AE  |   CJ
W   |   CK
M   |   CL
S   |   CM
Q   |   CN
Y   |   CO
AN  |   CP
V   |   CQ
AJ  |   CR
T   |   CS
AL  |   CT
AD  |   CU
Z   |   CV
AC  |   CW
U   |   CX
CV  |   CY
AA  |   CZ
CY  |   DA
X   |   DB
CX  |   DC
```

I tried basing the code of that, but as I quickly learned, after moving one column, all the proceeding columns shift.  Total failure!  I'm desperate for ideas!!

Comment: It will be much simpler to copy all of the columns to a new sheet, in the order you want them. That way you don't need to manage the shifting columns.  FYI if you include your existing code (even if it has issues) you're more likely to get help here.

Comment: In the future please posts your code attempts with your question.   Working code should be posted on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel allows you to sort columns.  You will have to adjust the `NewOrder` array but it will sort the data in less than 1 second.

```
Sub SortColumns()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim NewOrder As Variant
    NewOrder = Array(12, 34, 82, 33, 41, 10, 50, 52, 43, 44, 54, 55, 46, 45, 47, 48, 49, 53, 51, 62, 77, 58, 79, 80, 59, 78, 81, 2, 3, 4, 5, 99, 60, 61, 101, 76, 75, 74, 107, 105, 106, 11, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 104, 42, 56, 32, 83, 84, 85, 98, 1, 57, 14, 15, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 6, 7, 8, 9, 18, 16, 35, 39, 28, 37, 31, 23, 13, 19, 17, 25, 40, 22, 36, 20, 38, 30, 26, 29, 21, 100, 27, 103, 24, 102)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME)
        .Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        .Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(NewOrder) + 1).Value = NewOrder
        Set Target = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Target.Rows(1), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
                             xlSortNormal
        With .Sort
            .SetRange Target
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        .Rows(1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome!  Can you possibly expand on what you mean by "adjust the neworder array"?  Forgive me, but very much a novice here.

Comment: Makes sense!  I updated accordingly: NewOrder = Array(62, 28, 29, 30, 31, 78, 79, 80, 81, 6, 42, 1, 90, 64, 65, 83, 92, 82, 91, 97, 102, 95, 89, 107, 93, 100, 104, 86, 101, 99, 88, 57, 4, 2, 84, 96, 87, 98, 85, 94, 5, 55, 9, 10, 14, 13, 15, 16, 17, 7, 19, 8, 18, 11, 12, 56, 63, 22, 25, 33, 34, 20, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 38, 37, 36, 21, 26, 23, 24, 27, 3, 58, 59, 60, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 61, 32, 103, 35, 109, 105, 54, 40, 41, 39)

..But after running the macro, my sheet remains unchanged.

Comment: I'm so appreciative of your help!  My data is confidential so the best I can offer you is a sheet of Column A, Column B, etc.. can confirm data/headers in A1 thr DC1.

Comment: Sadly I'm on a work pc and it wont allow me to view an unprotected workbook.

Comment: ok, took me a minute to figure out I needed to change to activesheet and tweak my array, but finally got it working properly this afternoon!  Thank you SO much for your help!

Comment: @user7287846 Thanks for accepting my answer.  Cheers :)